# Who delves into "dikduk"?

Tags: grammar-dikduk

i am looking for seforim \ rabbis that discuss the specific details of dikduk \ grammar as well as "explanations" of the different tagim and trop (tunes) for the Torah reading.

Comment: tagim aren't related to dikduk/grammar

Comment: encyclopedia talmudit

Answer (score 2):

To check out the major early **dikduk** players see here: [https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/מדקדקי_העברית_בימי_הביניים](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A7%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D)

Similarly to examine **trop / ta'amei hamikra** see here:
[https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/טעמי_המקרא](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90), and for a good start, see R. Mordechai Breuer's section in the intro to **דעת מקרא על בראשית**, and then hop into his fairly well known sefer **טעמי המקרא בכ"א ספרים ובספרי אמ"ת**.

To begin your exploration into **tagim**, maybe see here:
[https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/אותיות_סת"ם#התגים](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A1%D7%AA%22%D7%9D#%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9D)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://hebrewbooks.org/20929) is a nice short sefer on dikduk from the Ibn Ezra, which also discusses many of the  great rabbis who preceded him in this topic.